# geowebcache-miss-reason:not a tile layer

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I've set up a single layer in Geoserver and added a tiled-layer to use for caching. I've also set up a custom gridset but when i request a tile i only get the response:

> geowebcache-cache-result:MISS
>
> geowebcache-miss-reason:not a tile layer

I'm probably missing something fundamental here but i don't get any of the other errormessages.

Do anyone have any idea what can cause this except not having added a tiled-layer.

The geoserver docs state that the error message is generated because:

> "The following request is not handled by the GeoWebCache WMS because
>   the layer requested has no tile layer configured" (Geoserver docs)

Any ideas?

Comment: please edit your question to tell us more about your layer, what it is? how it was added? etc

Comment: And also, what does the request look like?

Answer (score 1):

In my particular situation the problem was that I was accessing a Layer Group, instead of a layer. As soon as I switched it to request a single layer, caching started working.

This page has some useful information: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/troubleshooting.html